# python class not instantiated - ways to catch/debug?

Tags: python, error-handling

Im having some trouble with a python module (webpy.session) and Ive narrowed the problem down to a class not being instantiated.

Is there a way I can catch this happening and log the reason/error to a log file?

p.s (Ive tried running it in the python console and it works without error there)

Comment: Can you post the code in what isn't being instantiated? Does `MyClass()` not return an instance of that class?

Comment: db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='auth', user='root', pw='')
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={})   - its the last line which should instantiate a session class. P.s its a web.py session handler

Comment: Is it not obvious, when a class doesn't create object, it does mean that Session constructor or __init__ throws exception?

Comment: I think something like this (or maybe something simpler) is what im looking for - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457666-debuging-of-object-instantiation/

Answer (score 0):

I use `pdb` to debug this kind of thing.

For example, to debug the code you posted, I would add:

```
db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='auth', user='root', pw='')
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # BREAK <<<< this line
session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={})
```

Which would let me step into the function (using `s`), see what's returned, etc.

Bonus tip, if you use vim: `map <F8> oimport pdb; pdb.set_trace() # BREAK<esc>`